# XSLT 1.0: max value of a date node

Tags: xpath, lxml

Given following xml:

```
<Ergebnisse>
    <Spiel>
        <Datum>2013-10-02</Datum>
    </Spiel>
    <Spiel>
        <Datum>2013-10-03</Datum>
    </Spiel>
    <Spiel>
        <Datum>2013-10-03</Datum>
    </Spiel>
    <Spiel>
        <Datum>2013-10-03</Datum>
    </Spiel>
    <Spiel>
        <Datum>2013-10-06</Datum>
    </Spiel>
    <Spiel>
        <Datum>2013-10-06</Datum>
    </Spiel>
    <Spiel>
        <Datum>2013-10-06</Datum>
    </Spiel>
    <Spiel>
        <Datum>2013-10-06</Datum>
    </Spiel>
    <Spiel>
        <Datum>2014-05-01</Datum>
    </Spiel>
    <Spiel>
        <Datum>2014-05-01</Datum>
    </Spiel>
    <Spiel>
        <Datum>2014-04-27</Datum>
    </Spiel>
</Ergebnisse>
```

Now I need to know, which is the highest date-value in "Datum". I'm using Python and lxml, so I can only work with Xpath 1.0.
I tried:

```
//Spiel[not (Datum < preceding::Spiel/Datum) and not (Datum < following::Spiel/Datum)]/Datum
```

but it returns all values. What can I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0 you can sort the values and take the last.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Speil/Datum">
  <xsl:sort select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="position()=last()"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I wouldn't attempt it in XPath alone - if XPath 1.0 is all you have, return all the values and do the extraction in the Python host language.